# PYTHON: Convert each CSV Row into XML File sepperate

Tags: python, xml

i have a dic:

```
if os.path.isfile(pFile) and pFile.endswith(ext):
            with open(pFile, 'r') as pData:
                reader = csv.reader(pData)
                pData = {}
                for row in reader:
                    pData  ={'pData1' : row[0], 'pData2' : row[1]}
```

my pFile is my CSV File by the way (nearly 200 rows)
I'd like to convert my dict pData into XML but each row should saved seperate.

Which means that i should have 200 xml files at the end

My xml:

```
        root = minidom.Document()
        xml = root.createElement('Test')
        root.appendChild(xml)

        rowOne = root.createElemen('pData1')
        rowOne.appendChild(root.createTextNode('pData[pData1]')
        xml.appendChild(rowOne)

        rowTwo = root.createElemen('pData2')
        rowTwo.appendChild(root.createTextNode('pData[pData2]')
        xml.appendChild(rowTwo)

        xml_str = root.toprettyxml(indent="\t")
        with open(outputFile, 'w') as xmlData:
        xmlData.write(xml_str)
```

The Problem i have here is that i received just on XML File not 200.

Can anyone help me please.

Complete Code:

```
pFile = 'test.csv'
oFile = 'test.xml'


if os.path.isfile(pFile) and pFile.endswith(ext):
    with open(pFile, 'r') as pData:
        reader = csv.reader(pData)
        pData = {}
        for row in reader:
            pData  ={'pData1' : row[0], 'pData2' : row[1]}

            root = minidom.Document()
            xml = root.createElement('Test')
            root.appendChild(xml)

            rowOne = root.createElemen('pData1')
            rowOne.appendChild(root.createTextNode('pData[pData1]')
            xml.appendChild(rowOne)

            rowTwo = root.createElemen('pData2')
            rowTwo.appendChild(root.createTextNode('pData[pData2]')
            xml.appendChild(rowTwo)

            xml_str = root.toprettyxml(indent="\t")
            with open(oFile, 'w') as xmlData:
                xmlData.write(xml_str)
```

Comment: You realize that you overwrite the same output XML file for every row of your CSV?

Comment: @Tomalak that's the point :D

Comment: Yeah, so ... don't do that? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overwriting the same file everytime in your loop. You need to change the file-name as well:

```
pFile = 'test.csv'
oFile = 'test' #add xml later

if os.path.isfile(pFile) and pFile.endswith(ext):
    with open(pFile, 'r') as pData:
        reader = csv.reader(pData)
        pData = {}
        for i, row in enumerate(reader, 1):  #count each loop and store count-number in 'i', start with 1.
            pData  ={'pData1' : row[0], 'pData2' : row[1]}

            root = minidom.Document()
            xml = root.createElement('Test')
            root.appendChild(xml)

            rowOne = root.createElemen('pData1')
            rowOne.appendChild(root.createTextNode('pData[pData1]')
            xml.appendChild(rowOne)

            rowTwo = root.createElemen('pData2')
            rowTwo.appendChild(root.createTextNode('pData[pData2]')
            xml.appendChild(rowTwo)

            xml_str = root.toprettyxml(indent="\t")
            with open(oFile + '_' + str(i) + '.xml', 'w') as xmlData: #Give each file a new name with its current loop number
                xmlData.write(xml_str)
```

Comment: Happy to help. It also might be helpful for others if you mark the answer as correct.